# Grade 1 Music Theory

Tags: theory, exam-grades

I have 2 questions:

1. I have learned some topics of grade 1 but I think there are a lot of topics in it. Can anyone provide a list of topic which come under the Grade 1 syllabus and which I must go through prior jumping to Grade 2?
2. Is there website or any channel on Youtube which covers all the topics?

Comment: Go straight to the examination board websites. In UK it's Trinity, LCM or ABRSM. The syllabi are all set out, including sample questions.

Comment: Which methods??

Comment: @NeilMeyer - no one mentioned any methods.

Comment: When i say method i mean ABRSM, trinity, UNISA. All will have different answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note values of semibreve, minim, crotchet, quaver and semiquaver, and their equivalent rests
(candidates may use the terms ‘whole note’, ‘half note’, etc.). Tied notes. Single-dotted notes and rests.
2 Simple time signatures of 24 34 4 , bar-lines and the grouping of the notes listed above within these times.
3 The stave. Treble (G) and bass (F) clefs. Names of notes on the stave, including middle C in both clefs.
Sharp, flat and natural signs, and their cancellation.
4 Construction of the major scale, including the position of the tones and semitones. Scales and key signatures of the major keys of C, G, D and F in both clefs, with their tonic triads (root position), degrees (number only), and intervals above the tonic (by number only).
5 Some frequently used terms and signs concerning tempo, dynamics, performance directions and articulation marks. Simple questions will be asked about a melody written in either treble or bass clef.

Answer (score -1):

I took Theory I and II at a university and basically the material below i what they gave me (minus the Youtube channel)

**Beginner Level Theory:**

Read `Tonal Harmony` by Kostka (Buy the workbook as well - this is a separate book) (Buy an older version - way cheaper and same info)

The main things to focus on is circle of fifths, voice leading (avoiding parallel octaves and fifths), counterpoint, analysis, figured bass, roman numerals,intervals, interval inversion and chord construction... really, you can skip chapters later on in the book, but don't do it early in the book. Theory is much like math where as you miss one part and you're doomed to understanding anything past that.

Work on aural skills out of `a new approach to sight singing` by Berkowitz

[musictheory.net](http://musictheory.net) for aural skill mastery (kind of like flash cards except online)

Youtube Channel: `Rick Beato` - this channel may be a little advanced, but he does have simple stuff too.

That will carry you to Theory III if not further.

It's been years and I'm still working on this same material; music theory is a **huge** topic - you can get your PHD in music theory alone.

Also notice that this focuses on classical theory. If you are a jazzer, you still want to learn the classical theory first, then move to jazz theory.

Comment: Syllabi vary in different parts of the world - where are you ( and where's the OP?)